# working jQuery code not working inside conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I would like to set an element content in case it is empty. 
The `html.erb` code is below:

```
<div class="comments-section">
  <% if micropost.comments.any? %>
    <ol id="comments_micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
      <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= render comment %>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The element I want to set the content is `<div class="comments-section">`. Its content is empty when the micropost has not yet comments. 
 
I handle the create action of comments with javascript in `create.js.erb`: I wrote two lines of code, depending on whether `micropost.comments` is nil or it is not nil:

Case 1: micropost has not yet comments (`micropost.comments.any?` is false):

```
$('#micropost-<%= @micropost.id %>').find('.comments-section').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/first_comment') %>");
```

Case 2: micropost has already comments (`micropost.comments.any?` is true):

```
var comments = $('ol#comments_micropost-<%= @micropost.id %>');
comments.append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: @comment) %>');
```

Both pieces of code work when are used separately. However the code of case 1 do not work when inserted together with case 2 in the following conditional:

```
if (comments == null) {
  $('#micropost-<%= @micropost.id %>').find('.comments-section').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/comments') %>");
} 
else {
  comments.append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: @comment) %>');
};
```

I do not understand why when `if (comments == null)` the code is not executed. I also tried with `if (comments == undefined)` and with `if (!comments)` with no improvements. 
 
Instead, the `else` part of the conditional is successfully executed.

Comment: No changes also with `comments.blank?` OR `comments == ''`. Yes `comments` is from `var comments`: how can I express length equal to 0?

Comment: @Asarluhi if length is greater than  0. than it is available . if length is 0 than it is not available.

Comment: Even `if (comments.length === null)` does not work. I do not know why, one of the above solutions should work at this point.

Comment: **how can I express length equal to 0** : `if (comments.length == 0)`...

Comment: can you just debug and print value of `comments`?

Comment: `if (comments.length == 0)` works! :)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon for completeness it would be interesting to debug and get the value of `comments`. However I tried to wrap the definition of `comments` into `logger.info` and it did not work. I am looking for documentation on how to debug js.erb files.

Comment: You cannot debug js with rails debug methods. Try this in your chrome/firefox developers console. `var comments = $('ol#comments_micropost-1');` where 1 is the micropost.id , and see what you get

Comment: @Iceman I wrote `$('ol#comments_micropost-1');` (of course not 1 but the id of a micropost without comments) in my web browser console, clicked enter and got `[]`, that is an empty array.

Comment: Great. Just an observation, this part of Rails is always the one I find most frustrating to use, modern day javascript programming. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: You should write an answer and accept it yourself, that is totally acceptable practice here on SO. Maybe change the title also to `Conditional not working in jquery` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A non-existent DOM element is considered by JavaScript as an object with `length = 0`. It is possible to verify this by using a web browser console, writing the DOM element and checking the console output. Choose a micropost without comments (say micropost with `id = 304`): `micropost.comments.any?` would be false and everything inside `div.comments-section` will not appear in the document. Open the console and write the following code at the prompt:

```
$('ol#comments_micropost-304');
```

The output will be:

1. `[]` in a Chromium based browser
2. `Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → 1, selector: "ol#comments_micropost-304" }` in Firefox

The original `if` statement does not work because the object is not null and having `length = 0`. Therefore the right if statement is: `if (comments.length == 0)`